# GitHub Package Registry NPM 400 Put Error

Tags: github, npm, github-package-registry

Sometimes it's possible to get an error like the following when trying to publish your NPM package to GitHub Package Registry using `npm publish`:

```
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/@myorg%2fmypackage - RepoAcceptsPackageUploads: Repository "myorg/mypackage" does not exist.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [GitHub documentation for authenticating with GitHub Package Registry](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-package-registry#authenticating-to-github-package-registry) if the repository that you are trying to publish the package to is a private repo, the personal access token that you authenticate with must have the following scopes:

- `read:packages`
- `write:packages`
- `repo`

In this case the `repo` scope was the one missing since it wasn't immediately clear that scope was needed to publish packages to private repos.